# Project Euler 72 Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

The idea is to find the number of irreducible fractions with denominator d<=1,000,000. This is my implementation using a prime sieve and Euler's totient function:

```
target=10**6
s=0
def primesSieve(limit):
    dictPrimes = {x:True for x in range(2, limit+1)}
    for i in dictPrimes:
        if dictPrimes[i]:
            for f in range(2*i,limit+1, i):
                dictPrimes[f] = False
    return([i for i in dictPrimes if dictPrimes[i]==True])
primes=primesSieve(10**3)
def tot(n,primes):
    result=n
    for i in primes:
        if n%i==0: result-=result/i
    if result==n: result-=1
    return result
for n in range(2,target+1):
    s+=tot(n,primes)
print(s)
```

I know this isn't the most efficient way to do it but I guess it should also work. However, I'm not getting the correct answer. Please help me figure out the error. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
The problem is that the sieve must also be up to 1,000,000. Now I get the correct answer.

Comment: `for i in dictPrimes` makes no guarantees about iteration order. Use a list.

Comment: @user2357112 or sort it afterwards

Comment: Thanks! Will try to sort and report back!

Comment: Tried returning sorted([...]) in the prime sieve but I'm still getting the same result :(

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2883602 instead of updating your question, you should answer your own question with the solution.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride OP said the answer is not correct, so it's not suitable for CR.

Comment: @mephy ah, my mistake